# For Java , Can I create a method use the another method in the same class? And if this class have a fields with the same class name? Can I call it

Tags: java

I have created a class named Test. And in this class, there are 4 fields. Two of them are same class Test. I created two methods that would also return the same type. And in the last method " remove", the code I write is not work? Is it possible write this.method1().fields if the method1() return the same type of this?

Thank you.

```
public class Test {
    public int key;
    public int value;
    public Test father;
    public Test Sibling;`

    public Test(int item, int obj){
        this.key = item;
        this.value = obj;
    }

    public Test reAssignKey(int input) {
        key = input;
        return father;
    }

    public Test reAssignValue(int output){
        value = output;
        return Sibling;
    }

    public int remove(){
        this.reAssignKey(3).Sibling = new Test(3,10);
        return this.reAssignKey(3).Sibling.key;
    }
 }
```

Comment: And if it possible to write  this.Silbing.reAssignKey(3) = ..........

Comment: Your use of the `remove()` method in this way seems strange to me.  What is the logic behind `remove` ?

Comment: this.reAssignKey(3) will return null in your case, hence it will through null  pointer exception

Comment: I just use it for example. "remove" here is no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Sibling` (and `father`) are never initialized. So you'll get a `NullPointerException` whenever you call `remove()`.

Comment: Thank you. If  I want to use it. I need to initialize those two fields " Sibling" and "Father" , if I change reAssignkey method to    "return father = new Test(2,4) ". Is it worked in the "remove" method. Thank you

Comment: I didn't understand your question correctly. But even if you change your code in `remove()` to `return father = new Test(2,4)`, it returns a `Test` object where the fields `father' and `Sibling` are not initialized. You will only be able to access the `key` and `value` fields of the returned object without getting an exception.